# Format the data table of the highcharts.com library

Tags: javascript, laravel, highcharts, datatable

I'm working in Laravel and I'm making a chart with the highcharts.com library and I'm already formatting the chart with values in thousands,
but this library also has a data table, but this table is not formatted with values in thousands, below I share my code

```
<div class="">
    <figure class="highcharts-figure">
        <div id="container"></div>
    </figure>
</div>

<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script>
        var anio = {!! json_encode($anio) !!};
        var mes = {!! json_encode($mes) !!}; ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'];
        var venta = {!! json_encode($venta) !!}; ['1356940858.000000', '1945419126.000000', '934706589.000000', '1803607453.000000', '78415027.000000']


        venta = venta.map(function(value) {
            return parseFloat(value);
        });

        Highcharts.setOptions({
            lang: {
                thousandsSep: ','
            }
        });

        Highcharts.chart('container', {
            chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Ventas Mensuales',
                align: 'left',
                style: {
                    fontSize: '16px'
                }
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: mes, // Uses the JavaScript array "mes" for month names
                crosshair: true,
                accessibility: {
                    description: 'Meses'
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Ventas Mensuales'
                },
                labels: {
                    format: '{value:,.0f}'
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ' (COP)'
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    pointPadding: 0.2,
                    borderWidth: 0,
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        formatter: function() {
                            return '$' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 0);
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Ventas',
                data: venta
                // data: valoresY
            }],
            data: {
                table: 'datatable'
            },
            exporting: {
                tableCaption: "Tabla de Ventas Mensuales"
            }

        });


    </script>
```

Just this link `<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>` is the one that generates the data Table, next I share images how it looks like

[Imagen 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otAKr.png)

[Imagen 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rk2v.png)

the sales value is the one that I want to show formatted in thousands in the data Table

Comment: Hi @sergio241, just to confirm, could you please specify the preferred format for the table: 1356940858.000000 or a different one?

Comment: the Format I want is with numerical with thousands Example: (1580 to 1,580), (5895785 to 5,895,785).
whit this number 1356940858.000000 to 1,356,940,858

Comment: Thanks for clarifying - I added the answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by adding the event, that will modify the values in the table. Check the following example:

```
let H = Highcharts;

H.addEvent(H.Chart, 'aftergetTableAST', function(e) {
  e.tree.children[2].children.forEach(function(row) {
    row.children.forEach(function(cell, i) {
      if (i !== 0) {
        let num = parseFloat(cell.textContent.replace(',', ''));
        if (!isNaN(num)) {
          cell.textContent = num.toLocaleString();
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/yoqzvfp9/